# Column row align using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, css, mysql

I want it to be like this, the alignment but different info from database:

[image: Image 1]

It shows like this:

[image: Image 2]

```
<?php
  include_once('connection.php');


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblstdpro

ORDER BY StdID DESC limit 0, 8";



  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

  $count = 0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


     $StudentID="<a href='ProfileRecords.php?id=".$row['StdID']."'>".$row['StdID']."</a>";
   $StdName="<a href='ProfileRecords.php?id=".$row['StdID']."'>" . $row['Fname'] . ' ' . $row['Lname'] . "</a>";

  ?>
  <!--  Select distinct stdname, stdimage from tblstdpro order by stdid desc -->
          <div class="box-tools pull-right">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body no-padding">

                  <ul class="users-list clearfix">
                    <li>
                      <img src="<?php echo $row['StdImage'];?>" width="125px" alt="Student Image">
                      <a class="users-list-name" href="#"><?php echo "$StdName" ?></a>
                      <span class="users-list-date"><?php echo "$StudentID" ?></span>
                    </li>

                    </li>
                   <?php 
                   } ?>
                  </ul>

                  <!-- /.users-list -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
                <div class="box-footer text-center">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="uppercase">View All Users</a>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-footer -->
              </div>
              <!--/.box -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.row -->
```

Please show me the code I should add.

Comment: Can you show what the expected output is? And show what it actually displaying?  Gut instinct says, the ORDER BY does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply css to ul so that li items are displayed in line and not in a column. This is what I have come up with. Hope this helps..

```
         <style>
         /***Student list***/

        ul#stdList{
        width:fit-content;
        margin:15px auto 10px auto;
        overflow:hidden;
        }

        ul#stdList li{
        letter-spacing:.05em;
        color:#0a93cd;
        display:block;
        float:left;
        font:24px arial;
        padding:7px 7px;
        margin:0px 4px;
        text-align:center;
        }

        ul#stdList li:hover{
        border-color:#444;
        }

        .img-circle {
        border-radius: 50%;
        }

     </style>
```

HTML:

```
                <ul class="users-list clearfix" id="stdList">
                <li>
                  <img class="img-circle" src="images/std2.jpg" width="125px" alt="Student Image"><br/>
                  <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Name</a>
                  <span class="users-list-date">Student Id</span>
                </li>
                                   <li>
                  <img class="img-circle" src="images/std3.jpg" width="125px" alt="Student Image"><br/>
                  <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Name</a>
                  <span class="users-list-date">Student Id</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img class="img-circle" src="images/std4.jpg" width="125px" alt="Student Image"><br/>
                  <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Name</a>
                  <span class="users-list-date">Student Id</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img class="img-circle" src="images/std5.jpg" width="125px" alt="Student Image"><br/>
                  <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Name</a>
                  <span class="users-list-date">Student Id</span>
                </li>                    
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look closely to the position of your `while` block. You're not looping a single user (the `li` element), but a whole bunch of code before and after that. Amongst others the general toolbar buttons, and the whole list itself.